# MySQl Error while sending QUERY packet if Connection not closed and Reopened

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the `Warning Error while sending QUERY packet in PID=` when I use a `SELECT` statement that only gets **5 rows of data from 2 columns**, then make the script sleep for 10 minutes before waking up to continue an `INSERT` into the db.

If I close the connection after the `SELECT` statement and reopen the connection just before the `INSERT`, then everything works fine and no error is produced.

I can't figure out why this is happening. I'm on a public shared server.

**Select**

The values selected are:
`Seller` which is 10 characters in length and `Token` which is 872 in length.

```
include('con.php');
if ($result = $con->query("SELECT Seller,Token FROM `Sellers`")) { 
    $sellers = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $result->close();
}
$con->close();
```

**Sleep**

```
sleep(600);
```

**Insert**

All values being inserted are minimal in length of which 21 characters is the longest in the column `jobType`. Total of 5 rows being inserted from the foreach loop.

```
include('con.php');
foreach(...) {
    $insert = "INSERT INTO `jobStatus` (ack, jobId, RefId, Type, Status, error, percent, Seller, creationTime, completionTime) VALUES ('$ack', '$jid', '$frid', '$jtyp', '$jstat', '$errc', '$pcom', '$sid', '$crtime', '$cotime')";

    if($con->query($insert)) {
        echo "inserted into db successfully.\n";
    } else {
        echo "not inserted into db. Query Failed.\n";
    }
}
$con->close();
```

Above code works without an error because of closing and reopening the connection in between the statements.

I want it to work without the error when I keep the connection open after the `SELECT` and then closing the connection after the `INSERT`.

Can someone point out what I need to do in order to accomplish this?

Note: I already have the set_time_limit set to 0 in my script.

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Here is the code which produces the error.

**Code that causes error**

**Select**

```
include('con.php');
if ($result = $con->query("SELECT Seller,Token FROM `Sellers`")) { 
    $sellers = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $result->close();
}
```

**Sleep**

```
sleep(600);
```

**Insert**

```
foreach($sellers as $seller) {
    $insert = "INSERT INTO `jobStatus` (ack, jobId, RefId, Type, Status, error, percent, Seller, creationTime, completionTime) VALUES ('$ack', '$jid', '$frid', '$jtyp', '$jstat', '$errc', '$pcom', '$sid', '$crtime', '$cotime')";

    if($con->query($insert)) {
        echo "inserted into db successfully.\n";
    } else {
        echo "not inserted into db. Query Failed.\n";
    }
}
$con->close();
```

**Update:**

Here are the results of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout'`

```
$SESSION_VARIABLES = array(
    array(
        "Variable_name" => "connect_timeout",
        "Value" => "10",
    ),
    array(
        "Variable_name" => "delayed_insert_timeout",
        "Value" => "300",
    ),
    array(
        "Variable_name" => "innodb_flush_log_at_timeout",
        "Value" => "1",
    ),
    array(
        "Variable_name" => "innodb_lock_wait_timeout",
        "Value" => "50",
    ),
    array(
        "Variable_name" => "innodb_rollback_on_timeout",
        "Value" => "OFF",
    ),
    array(
        "Variable_name" => "interactive_timeout",
        "Value" => "30",
    ),
    array(
        "Variable_name" => "lock_wait_timeout",
        "Value" => "86400",
    ),
    array(
        "Variable_name" => "net_read_timeout",
        "Value" => "30",
    ),
    array(
        "Variable_name" => "net_write_timeout",
        "Value" => "60",
    ),
    array(
        "Variable_name" => "slave_net_timeout",
        "Value" => "60",
    ),
    array(
        "Variable_name" => "thread_pool_idle_timeout",
        "Value" => "60",
    ),
    array(
        "Variable_name" => "wait_timeout",
        "Value" => "30",
    ),
);
```

Comment: what you've shown appears to be the working version, is that right? Can you show us the non-working version as well? Seeing as that's what you want fixing...

Comment: P.S. I just noticed "then make the script sleep for 10 minutes"...why are you doing that? Possibly your connection times out.

Comment: sure ok, basically it is the above, but without closing and reopening the connection.

Comment: @ADyson no the connection does not timeout.

Comment: So removing the first `$con->close();` and the second `include('con.php');`, I take it? And `foreach(...) {` what's the real version of that?

Comment: " the connection does not timeout. " how do you know?

Comment: @ADyson because if I use an array instead of a `SELECT` from the db, then I do not get a error and the `INSERT` will work fine even with a sleep of 10 min beforehand.

Comment: And why are you sleeping for 10 minutes? It's unusual. Does it work if you remove the sleep (but still use the SELECT)?

Comment: And `foreach(...) {` what's the real version of that? What are you looping over?

Comment: @ADyson I will add the real version above in my question. I am sleeping for 10 min to let the 3rd party website script do its thing, then after 10 min I have to check to see if it finished to retrieve the data from it.

Comment: And precisely which line of code is generating the warning? If it's in the loop which does the INSERTs, on which iteration of the foreach do you get the warning?

Comment: @ADyson 1st iteration of loop. The `insert` is never executed.

Comment: P.S. with such a big interval between your queries, why do you care about keeping the connection open? What issue are you trying to solve with that? It's hardly inefficient, with such a gap in between. Plus if your server supports connection pooling, it will handle the actual opening and closing through that - your PHP commands will simply take connections from the pool, and return them afterwards, rather than literally opening and closing them.

Comment: @ADyson from what I've read, keeping a connection open is the most efficient way to go. A connection should be able to stay open for 8 hours without an issue. So, 10 min should be no problem at all. What do I need to do in my code to take advantage of the `pooling`?

Comment: @ADyson btw, even if I set to sleep for 60 seconds, still the error is produced. However, if I set it lower to like 20 seconds, then no error is produced and the `INSERT` will execute and data will be inserted in db.

Comment: @Mike can you post the result of the query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout'`?

Comment: @ThomasLeu I will post the show variables results above in my question for you to see. Give me a few min.

Comment: @ThomasLeu check out the results posted above in update

Comment: @Mike What you posted is not exactly what I meant. I was just trying to verify that the timeout is 8h like you claimed. But it looks like you do not have the rights to execute this query... Do you have e. g. phpmyadmin where you can try to execute it? if it does not work, you could try `SELECT @@wait_timeout ` and `SELECT @@interactive_timeout `... However I would definitely consider using [mysqli::ping](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.ping.php) to reconnect if necessary

Comment: "What do I need to do in my code to take advantage of the pooling" ...nothing, it all happens in the background, if it's enabled. Your code doesn't need to change at all. See the "connection pooling" section here. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Comment: @ThomasLeu ok sorry. I re-posted in the above update the response from the query you gave me.

Comment: P.S. " from what I've read, keeping a connection open is the most efficient way to go"...hm, I'd say that was only true if you're actually using it. Opening and closing a connection has an overhead, yes, but it only becomes noticeable if you repeatedly open and close it many times within a few seconds. People advise you not to close and re-open when doing things in quick succession, e.g. when web apps make lots of queries to build a page. Then you'd notice it slowing down....

Comment: ....But if there's 10 minutes between the queries then you'll never notice any problem. In fact you could argue that holding onto a connection you know you won't be using is actually _less_ efficient, because there is a limit on the number of concurrent connections allowed on any DB server, and so in theory you're potentially preventing another process from using that connection, and you're also keeping data in memory which is not being used....

Comment: ...Again consider a web app - if someone makes a request which runs a query (which returns in a few seconds), then 10 minutes later makes another request to run a query, no-one will say it's inefficient for the webserver to use a new connection for that second request. Certainly no-one would expect it to try and hold a connection open until it receives another request. I think you are trying to solve a bit of a non-issue here.

Comment: @ADyson ok thanks for the good advice. I'll stick to closing the con and re opening it 10 min later after script wakes up.

Answer (score 1):

The mysql connection times out after 30 seconds, i. e., gets closed automatically after 30 seconds of inactivity and there is nothing you can do about it (except polling it every 29 seconds while sleeping). I suggest you use [mysqli::ping](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.ping.php) after the sleep to reconnect if necessary:

```
if ($con->ping()) {
    // foreach... insert
}
```

Comment: Ok will try this and report back.